# How can I use Family Sharing for Store purchases if I use a different Apple ID for purchases?

Tags: itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, family-sharing

A key feature of Apple's iCloud Family Sharing is the ability to share store purchases with invited family members. However, like many people, I use [a different Apple ID for iCloud and Store purchases](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59974/4395) (ironically, primarily for the exact purpose of sharing among family).

Can I use iCloud Family Sharing to share purchases if I use a different Apple ID for Store (iTunes, App Store, etc.) purchases? I understand that if I send invitations from the ID I use for purchases, I can share them; but there seems to be no way to do this, given that I use a different ID for iCloud on all my devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works exactly as one would expect it to: When you share from an iOS 8 device, purchases made with the Apple ID used on that device for purchases (iTunes, iBooks, AppStore) — *even if that ID is different from the one used for iCloud (Photos, Mail, Contacts, Calendars) on that device* — will be shared.