# Apple ID password vs iCloud password - better to be the same or different?

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id, password

I have too many passwords to track on too many devices. With my apple devices & services, it would be easier for me if both my iCloud and Apple ID passwords were the same.

Should this be ok or is it bad security practice? Is there a recommendation? What do most people do?

Comment: Not great for security, great for remembering which is which. I have 2 Apple IDs, one from long before iCloud was ever dreamed up. Until I made the passwords AND security questions the same I was forever getting locked out.

Comment: this may be of interest http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59974/should-i-use-the-same-apple-id-for-icloud-and-itunes?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

First, you usually don't need a [different Apple ID for iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204053):

> We recommend that you use the same Apple ID for Store purchases and iCloud. Using multiple Apple IDs might be confusing and might cause issues with accessing purchased content or using some services.

If you do have two Apple ID's, [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201303) has this to say about reusing passwords:

> Avoid using your Apple ID password with other online accounts.

Password reuse is problematic because all your security depends on the "weakest link", the less secure –or more exposed– service. Once that service is compromised, all your services are.

[XKCD](https://xkcd.com) has [this to say](https://xkcd.com/792/) about the subject:

[image: XKCD Password reuse comic]

On the matter of remembering passwords, [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/) –sorry, again– has some iconic graphical input, analyzed and validated [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) by the people at InfoSec SE.

[image: XKCD password strenght]

In a nutshell, passwords must be difficult to guess and easy to remember, and he proposes the use of passphrases instead of short, complicated passwords.

Yet [others](http://lifehacker.com/5785420/the-only-secure-password-is-the-one-you-cant-remember) think that

> The Only Secure Password Is the One You Can’t Remember

which is my philosophy by the way.
In order to achieve this apparent nonsense, you use a Password manager, ([iCloud Keychain](https://www.apple.com/support/icloud/keychain/), [Keepass](https://www.keepassx.org/), [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword), [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)), and generate different random secure passwords for every service. You only have to remember one master password –where you could apply XKCD's idea.

People have [different](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/password-manager-vs-remembering-passwords) [opinions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/279/online-password-managers) on how secure password managers are; if you are a bit paranoid or have very sensitive data you may want to have an [eidetic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory) instead, although one [known cryptographer and security expert](https://www.schneier.com/about.html) [advocates the use of at least one](https://www.schneier.com/passsafe.html) –not cloud synced, though.

Comment: However normal apple ids (those that end with **gmail.com**) have limited features (can't access mail/notes/etc) in iCloud. We'd still need a `@icloud` account.

Comment: @Pacerier I haven't heard of this "normal" Apple IDs you describe. I don't think I understand the second part of your assertion.

Comment: Is your Apple Id username ending with @ icloud or one that doesn't?

Comment: It does not end on @ icloud.com